# new File(...).eachFileRecurse() fails on existing files and folders

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Currently I'm refactoring our Jenkins build pipeline. In the stage of gathering our unittests I'm trying to enumerate all '**/*.test.dll' files, or '*.test.dll' at least. Read somewhere that this could be achieved using `eachFileRecurse` from the `File`-object.

But... all calls failed reporting `FileNotFoundException`.
Using the Scriptconsole on the specific slave I tried the same code and it works as expected. Adding some addition debug lines in our jenkins-file shows that the pipeline always returns false.

```
def TestFile(path)
{
    def file = new File(path)

    echo "File '${file}' exists: ${file.exists()}"
}
TestFile(WORKSPACE)
TestFile(pwd())
TestFile(BUILDPATH)
```

All result a 'exists: false', even though all these paths are already used during the build.

(How) can I use the `File`-object in a pipeline or how can I get the files I need?

Answer (score 0):

Use `fileExists` together otherwise it will not work.

For example in your case it will be like this

```
echo "fileExists '${file}' exists: '${file}'"
```